# Best practice save product image in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, performance, structure

I have a photo per products for example

cook book -> cook_book.jpg

for this, I create a column in products table for image name

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|       product_name    |       image_name       |
--------------------------------------------------
|       cook book       |     cook_book.jpg      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

and I save this image in the `Storage` path

```
/storage/app/image

- small_cook_book.jpg
- large_cook_book.jpg
- thumb_cook_book.jpg
- bw_small_cook_book.jpg
- bw_large_cook_book.jpg
- bw_thumb_cook_book.jpg
- ... (other image for other products)
```

`bw` in `bw_thumb_cook_book.jpg`= black and white images

As you can see I need 3 different sizes And for every size I need a black and white image

Is there a better way to create this structure?

For example, more folders Or save all addresses in the database or convert to black and white at the moment of receiving or changing the size of the image at the moment of receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practise to store a large amount of files in one single directory, but also I can not see a reason to split the 6 photos needed for each product in subfolders.

One solution is to have a folder for each product, i.e.

```
/storage/app/image/product_key_1/all_images_here
/storage/app/image/product_key_2/all_images_here
etc.
```

But if you plan to have thousands of products, I am afraid you will have performance issues. 
Then, you might separate them by year of creation (the Wordpress way), i.e.

```
/storage/app/image/2020/01/product_key_1/all_images_here
/storage/app/image/2020/02/product_key_2/all_images_here
etc.
```

or by the first two letters of the product key (the Magento way), i.e.

```
/storage/app/image/p/r/product_key_1/all_images_here
/storage/app/image/o/t/other_product_key/all_images_here
etc.
```

or use a storage like amazon s3.

Comment: I have 20,000 products. Do I have a problem with the first solution you provided?

Comment: I wouldn't go with the first solution in your case, If I were you I would choose one of the other two or something similar, and also consider going with a third-party like amazon s3 or digitalocean.

Answer (score -1):

storage/app/images/{PRODUCT_ID}/{SIZE}/{BW|COLOR}

create folders like this:

when creating product create folder with the saved product id.

then inside that newly created folder create folder name size, then inside size folder create 2 more folders named BW & Color.

now whenever you need to remove the product you can delete any particular folder or file easily without messing with other files.

this is the best way. i'm using the same structure in my SaaS products, this way i can remember the images & i can access them directly instead of going to folders by folders.

Comment: Doesn't creating a folder for each one complicate or slow down?

Comment: no, as you will add product one by one so it will take only 0.2 mil seconds to create folders which is not much resource hogging..

Comment: So what information should I enter in the database?

Comment: nothing.. everything is set..

just add 1 more column in your products table.

ID